# Text game doesn't run

Tags: python

I have been working on a text game and I have no clue why it's not running.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import time

a = 2

dice1d6 = random.randint (1, 6)

def dicegame():

    play = input("Will you play the game? (Y/N): ")
    if play == 'y':
        print("Lets play then!")
        print(dice1d6)
        dice_save_1 = open("dice_save_1.txt", "a")
        dice_save_1.write(dice1d6)
        dice_save_1.close()
        time.sleep(a)
        dicegame()
    if play == 'n':
        print("Begone foolish mortal!")
        time.sleep(a)
        dicegame()
    else:
        print("Thats not an option...")
        time.sleep(a)
        dicegame()
```

What I meant by "not working" is I saw a flash of the command line but it didn't do anything after that.

Comment: Can you define 'not running'?  Are you just not seeing anything in the console?  When I run the code, it executes but I don't see a call to dicegame(), so it looks to me like you've defined the function but never called it

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a function (`dicegame()`) but never actually called it, which means nothing happens.

Second problem is that your write statement should write a string value not an int.  You can fix this by typecasting to str thus: `dice_save_1.write(str(dice1d6))`

It's also considered best practices to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` as the entry point for the program.  With that in mind, I would append these lines at the bottom of your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dicegame()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Not running" can mean many things, but I assume it is that when you run the .py nothings happens. Nothing is printed on screen.

This is because even though you define the function
`dicegame()`, you never actually call it. In order to do this, I would change the code to define the function and then call it, something like this:

```py
import random
import time

def dicegame():
    ...

a = 2
dice1d6 = random.randint (1, 6)
dicegame()
```

You can also [define a main function](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/) to make it even cleaner.

Your defined function is recursive and I am not sure that was intentional or not.